# "Bad version number in .class file" Is there a Maven plugin to check for this error?

Tags: java, maven

I'm stuck using Java 1.5. Sometimes I add a dep to my pom.xml and it's only Java 1.6 compatible. Is there a Maven plugin that can check for that?

Comment: Why are you stuck using Java 5?

Comment: @kittylyst Could be that they only have a license of an older version of WebSphere (et al.) that support Java 5, or a school that has not bothered to upgrade their lab computers etc. There are Fortune 500 companies out there still stuck on Java 1.4. I worked on such a project recently.

Comment: It's more to do with the licensing agreement of 1.6 as it pertains to client side development. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a maven plugin for that, but you can try to get the source of this dependency and compile with java 1.5 and then include it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Well in a sense Maven does check for that by failing. Just trying to build your code tells you that it does not work. I think what you mean to be asking is how can you check beforehand if a jar is Java 5 compatable and that I don't know. [MvnRepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) does not seem to support such a feature.

Comment: My code compiles fine, but the problem is with a dependency that is necessary, but rather than being transitive, I have to add it explicitly. The problem only occurs at runtime.